# Getting List of ESXs and system settings per ESX using pyVmomi

Tags: vmware, pyvmomi

What are the parallel pyVmomi API for the following esxcli commands:

```
esxcli system settings advanced list --option /DataMover/HardwareAcceleratedMove
esxcli system settings advanced list --option /DataMover/HardwareAcceleratedInit
esxcli system settings advanced list --option /VMFS3/HardwareAcceleratedLocking
esxcli system settings advanced list --option /VMFS3/EnableBlockDelete
esxcli storage nmp device list
```

I would like to get this info for all ESXs that resides in a specific datacenter

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import atexit

from pyVim import connect
from pyVmomi import vmodl
from pyVmomi import vim

import tools.cli as cli


def print_host_info(host_machine):
    """
    Print information for a particular host machine 
    """
    print host_machine.config.network.dnsConfig.hostName
    print host_machine.config.product.version
    for option in host_machine.config.option:
         if option.key in ('VMFS3.UseATSForHBOnVMFS5','DataMover.HardwareAcceleratedInit','DataMover.HardwareAcceleratedMove','VMFS3.HardwareAcceleratedLocking','VMFS3.EnableBlockDelete') :
             print option.key,option.value


def main():
    """
    Simple command-line program for listing the hosts machines on a system.
    """

    args = cli.get_args()

    try:
        service_instance = connect.SmartConnect(host=args.host,
                                                user=args.user,
                                                pwd=args.password,
                                                port=int(args.port))

        atexit.register(connect.Disconnect, service_instance)

        content = service_instance.RetrieveContent()

        container = content.rootFolder  # starting point to look into
        viewType = [vim.HostSystem]  # object types to look for
        recursive = True  # whether we should look into it recursively
        containerView = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(
            container, viewType, recursive)

        children = containerView.view
        for child in children:
            print_host_info(child)

    except vmodl.MethodFault as error:
        print("Caught vmodl fault : " + error.msg)
        return -1

    return 0

# Start program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```